# Replace float like number in line

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I would like to increase the version number in a config file in both lines which looks like this:

```
version:
  abc01: 1.13.0
  abc02: 1.13.0
```

To do that I have tried to use `sed` command - match `abc01` and `abc02` and then replace them with `abc0X 1.14.0` but I think it is not the ideal solution and it was missing TABs.

```
sed -i -e 's/.*abc01.*$/\abc01 1.14.0/g' config.yaml
```

Comment: Can you also share the `sed` command that you tried?

Comment: `sed -i -e 's/.*abc01.*$/\abc01 1.14.0/g' config.yaml` besides no TAB it was working.

Comment: Regarding the leading tabs, `.*` is matching them.  You don't need it if you do not want to replace them.  Sed's `s///` replacement will leave substrings that you don't match alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk -v FS='.' -v OFS='.' '/abc/{$2++} {print}' file
```

or

```
awk -v FS='.' -v OFS='.' '/abc/{$2++}1' file
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} /abc/{$2++}1' file
```

or

```
awk '/abc/{$2++}1' FS='.' OFS='.'  file
```

Output:

```
version:
  abc01: 1.14.0
  abc02: 1.14.0
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: Thanks! How to use awk to insert any version number not to increase it by +1?

Comment: Replace `$2++` with `$2=42`, e.g.

Comment: Thanks but in this way it is not possible to insert any version number i.e. for insert major version number I have to assign to `$1` also `abcXX`.

Answer (score 1):

If the `abc01` doesn't appear anywhere else in your input, the easiest way to solve this is to avoid matching the whitespaces in front of it so that you will leave it untouched :

```
sed -i -e 's/abc01.*$/abc01 1.14.0/g' config.yaml
```

If that isn't the case, then you can capture the start of the line in a capturing group you'll reference in your replacement pattern :

```
sed -i -E 's/(.*abc01).*$/\1 1.14.0/g' config.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -E 's/(abc0.: 1\.1)./\14/' config.yaml
```